# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/assets/level.png'

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, project, discord

So currently, I'm working on a project within an application you may know - Discord. I am currently trying to code a bot and have come to the task of getting it to send images from a local file source. My bot is hosted with Heroku which means all the files are local to the cloud it is on and every file I upload is maintained in the hierarchy it is in when pushed. Moreover, I have uploaded all the files I need and all the code is working and up-to-date apart from one little thing. The file that I want to send.

```
module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
    message.channel.send('', {files: ['../assets/level.png']});
};
```

These lines of code should send an image of a simple, grey rectangle (png) file. However.. it does not. Instead, my console returns these lines:

```
2019-01-16T19:58:24.366174+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/assets/level.png'
2019-01-16T19:58:24.366478+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated 
either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a 
promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

Any suggestions on what the fix might be would be great. Also, if you would like to contact me on what my current files look like, please don't hesitate to contact me on Discord @ I'mALittleTeapot#0001. Thank you.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory really: you have no file at the `/assets/level.png` location in your file system.
Sometimes errors are a bit hard to understand, this is definitely not one of those cases.

Comment: I do. Like I said, if you would like to see the files I have currently uploaded then you can simply ask to do so. Secondly, I had input `../assets/level.png` which is the main part I'm struggling to understand. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Try to replace the line with `message.channel.send('', {files: [__dirName+'/../assets/level.png']});`
If it works, I'll explain in an answer in a few words.

Answer (score 0):

according to the docs of discord.js (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=send)
(checked the textchannel channel.send() & it looks the same)

this is how you call that function:

```
// Send a local file
channel.send({
  files: [{
    attachment: 'entire/path/to/file.jpg',
    name: 'file.jpg'
  }]
})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

it looks like you need to provide a path for the attachment and a name for it (well the name is optional)

unsure of this but if channel.send does indeed support the syntax you used, then, **I would look into that "entire/path/to/file.jpg" which strongly suggests you can't use relative paths**.

Comment: Thank you for this comment but I fixed it by myself and for some reason it isn't picking up on the fact that the folder I'm working from goes `MainApp/commands/rank.js` so it would need to go `../` to get back to the `MainApp` folder so I have no idea what's happening there.

Comment: glad you sorted it out :)